# Fatal error Python kernel unresponsive Databricks

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

recently I am facing an issue in pyspark like Fatal error: python kernel unresponsive. is it memory error or some other type error? can someone please shed some light on it.

Comment: What runtime are you using?

Comment: I'm getting the same error in a job that runs OPTIMIZE on a moderately small table. Runtime 11.2. The problem appeared in the last month

Comment: Frustrating how this question isn't getting any attention. [This thread on the Databricks forum](https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D58Y00009AKNXVSA5/fatal-error-python-kernel-is-unresponsive) mentions how it is caused by running out of RAM on your cluster. Wish I could say more about what types of query / code can cause the issue, and how you could prevent it ...